# Showing small area between curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have attempted drawing the hyperbola `y=\dfrac{1}{x+1}` and the parabola `y=x^2-x+1` on the same set of axes as shown below. Currently, the graphs are not clearly indicating the area between curve for `-\dfrac{1}{2} < x < 0`. What would I need to change so that I display this area?

[image: current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$ $},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$ $}          % default put y on y-axis
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
xlabel={$ $},
ylabel={$y$},
grid=none,
height=13cm,
width=13cm,
ticks=none
]
\draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:-1,-5)--(axis cs:-1,5);
\node [below] at (axis cs: 0.2,0){$O$};
\node [above] at (axis cs: 4.9,0.2){$x$};
\node [below] at (axis cs: -1.3,0){$-1$};
%
\node [right,red] at (axis cs: 1.7,4.7){$y=2x^2-x+1$};
\node [right] at (axis cs: 3,0.7){$y=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
%
\addplot[thick,color=red,samples=100,domain=-3:3] {2*x^2-x+1};
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=-5:-1.2] {1/(x+1)};
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=-0.8:5] {1/(x+1)};
\draw[thick,fill=black] (axis cs:-0.5,2) circle (0.5mm);
\draw[thick,fill=black] (axis cs:0,1) circle (0.5mm);
\draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:-0.5,0)--(axis cs:-0.5,2);
\draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:-0.5,2)--(axis cs:0,2);
\node [below] at (axis cs: -0.5,0){$-\frac{1}{2}$};
\node [right] at (axis cs: 0,2){$2$};
\node [right] at (axis cs: 0,1.1){$1$};
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to zoom in a bit closer?  If so, you could adjust the axis limits, to something like `xmin=-0.6,xmax=0.6,ymin=0.5,ymax=2.5`

Comment: @Thruston I think the OP wants to show the area between the two-curves as stated in OP's statement before the last one.

Comment: @Raaja That's one reading, sure, but not the only reading. Hence my question.

Comment: @Thruston Understandable ;)

Comment: you can use spy library to zoom out

Answer (score 1):

One simplest way is to duplicate the path of the object by redrawing it again until the limits you envisage. Then use the well-known `fill-between` trick to achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1.5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
xlabel={$x $},
ylabel={$y$},
grid=none,
height=13cm,
width=13cm,
]
%
\addplot[name path= a,thick,color=red,samples=100,domain=-3:-0.5] {2*x^2-x+1};
\addplot[name path=b,thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=-0.8:-0.5] {1/(x+1)};
\addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=a and b];
\addplot[name path= a,thick,color=red,samples=100,domain=-3:3] {2*x^2-x+1};
\addplot[name path=b,thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=-0.8:5] {1/(x+1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Note: I removed most of your piece of code because, I could not compile your MWE. Hence, I retained only the skeleton of the necessary parts.